# Why [OneTimeSetUp] in [SetUpFixture] called after (Test,TestCaseSource())

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

I am stuck in strange situation in Nunit 3 testcases, My [OneTimeSetUp] in [SetUpFixture] is called after `[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(TestDataProvider), "GetSQLTestCases")]`.

Where as when I remove that `TestCaseSource` attribute from tests, then work as expected in order as given below.

OneTimeSetup -- > Test

Please advice me how to resolve said issue.

-Neeraj

Comment: This is suspicious. I bet the actual error is somewhere else. For example static constructors can be called before OneTimeSetUp.

Comment: So I think flow in Nunit3 design as `GetSQLTestCases` dynamic test supports on in `Static` method and I want to create database before execute that test cases in 'OnetimeSetup'

Answer (score 3):

That is expected. *All TestCaseSource targets are evaluated BEFORE any tests (or any SetUp/OneTimeSetUp method) is called.*

The order is:

```
(~ALL~ TestCaseSource in assembly) ->
  (SetupFixture ctor) ->
    (OneTimeSetUp) ->
      (TestFixture ctor) ->
        (SetUp) ->
          (Test)
```

This is because the RESULT of the TestCaseSource's is the list of data used to execute the tests; as this is the list of tests that will be run, it is generated at the start. (Old NUnit versions would create instances of classes to access non-static TestCaseSource targets.)

While likely *inadvisable*<sup>1</sup>, the TestCaseSource's backing static method could "load database stuff"<sup>2</sup>, as long as it doesn't depend on OneTimeSetUp being called first. TestCaseSources should be FAST<sup>3</sup> and resource-free as the time taken is "phantom time"<sup>4</sup> not accounted for within test.

<sup>1,2,3,4</sup>Failures to evaluate TestCaseSources, such as database errors, will result in tests being not-discoverable. All time taken evaluating TestCaseSources will *slow down every test exploration*. The time overhead of this evaluation is *not included* in individual test timings (even when running single tests) and is not shown using standard tooling. It is tedious to track down and fix such slow TestCaseSources later.